# Symfony security access_control syntax

Tags: symfony, security, fosuserbundle

I currently have the below code, which does pretty much what I want.
There's just a few things I don't understand.

What's the ^/ in front of each path?

What's the $ behind ^/login?

Why do I get redirected to the login page when I don't have access to a page? Where do I set this up or change this?

Is there an easy way to grant access to my frontpage (/) while requiring users to be logged in to access any other page (except for the login/register pages)?

Should I use IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY or ROLE_USER?

Can't find any clear info on the subject either ...

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_ATHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding ^ and $

^ = start of the string
$ = end of string

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Delimiters

IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY or ROLE_USER: 
You can't compare these 2 directly. You could be authenticated fully and not have the role user. 
IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY only means that you're not logged in through the remember_me mechanism in this session but actively entered your password.
It does not however check which role the logged in user is granted.

More here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#checking-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-is-authenticated-fully

> Is there an easy way to grant access to my frontpage (/) while requiring users to be logged in to access any other page (except for the login/register pages)?

Try:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: Seems to work, although  I don't fully understand why the 1st line is required or what the $ does exactly

Comment: The $ at the end mean "ends with", in this case (^/$) it means only the root path.